# Sybase join conversion to sql server

Tags: sql-server, join

I'm very new to sybase and finding hard to convert this join query to sql server. Any help is appreciated thanks.
Sybase Query

```
FROM A,B,C,D
WHERE (A.fd_id = :variable )
AND B.ct_id =* D.ct_comb_id
AND A.ct_in_id = D.ct_ind_id 
AND D.ct_comb_id *= C.ct_id
AND C.ct_type = 'H'
```

SQL server (I've tried)

```
FROM B
RIGHT OUTER JOIN D
ON B.ct_id = D.ct_comb_id
INNER JOIN A
ON A.ct_in_id = D.ct_ind_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN C
ON D.ct_comb_id *= C.ct_id
WHERE A.fd_id = :variable and C.ct_type = 'H'**
```

Comment: You're going to need to give us more to work with.  How are you populating the variables, for example?  What error are you receiving? What the heck does *= mean?

Comment: @Andrew `*=` means `LEFT JOIN` similarly `=*` means `Right Join` etc

Comment: In sybase (*= ) means left outer join and (=*) right outer join. I'm not facing any error and tricky situation is both sybase and sql server query output is empty. So i'm not able to test my conversion query. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.....

```
SELECT *
FROM A
INNER JOIN D   ON A.ct_in_id = D.ct_ind_id 
              AND A.fd_id = @variable
LEFT  JOIN C   ON D.ct_comb_id = C.ct_id
              AND C.ct_type = 'H' 
LEFT  JOIN B   ON B.ct_id = D.ct_comb_id
```

Comment: Thanks Ali. May I know why you have used both left joins. As original query has one right and left join ?

Comment: Yes I have user both left joins and I have also changed the order in which tables are  being joined, Having a LEFT JOIN and then a RIGHT JOIN doesnt make sense, anyway try it and make appropriate changes if needed.

Comment: Okay thanks. One last question the use of Where clause in sybase and you have used that condition in JOIN clause. Does the output gonna vary if I use separate where clause like (WHERE A.fd_id = :variable and C.ct_type = 'H') rather than in join clause ?

Comment: it doesnt make difference where you put the where clause condition if you only have inner joins, but in case of outer joins it can make a difference and it is best to use them in `ON`clause.